# My ReactMeteor Photo component refreshes the page when inside a form

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, camera, reactjs

I have a Photo component like this:

```
Photo=ReactMeteor.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
    return({
        photo:'Camera.png',
        photoClass:'mouseChange'
    });
},
takePicture:function(){
    var that = this;
    MeteorCamera.getPicture({}, function(error,data){
      if(error){
        alert(error.error);
      }else{
        that.setState({photo: data, photoClass:'pictureTaken'});
      }
    });
},
render:function(){
    return(
        <button>
          <img src={this.state.photo} className={this.state.photoClass} onClick={this.takePicture}/>
        </button>
    );
}   
});
```

When I use it outside a form it works as expected.

However inside the form it refreshes the page at the point where it would normally ask for the permission to use the camera. It then also changes the url of the page into something that I never configured.

In both cases I have added a `<Photo/>` tag. The change in class is meant to show the actual picture a bit bigger than the camera button.

meteor@1.1.6
mdg:camera@1.1.4
reactjs:react@0.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of the button on click is to submit the form and this causes a refresh. You need to prevent this default behavior.
The click event handler (in your case the takePicture method) gets the event as a parameter. What you need to do is call event.preventDefault();

So the code of your takePicture method should look as follows:

```js
takePicture: function(event){
    // This will prevent the refresh
    event.preventDefault();
  
    var that = this;
    MeteorCamera.getPicture({}, function(error,data){
      if(error){
        alert(error.error);
      }else{
        that.setState({photo: data, photoClass:'pictureTaken'});
      }
    });
}
```